# Should I have fixed supply or don't (ERC-20, ERC-1400)?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I've started learning ERC-20 from a tutorial in which the `totalSupply` parameter was used to limit the number of tokens to be created. Now I've started working on the ERC-1400 token (specifically the [ConsenSys's implementation](https://github.com/ConsenSys/UniversalToken)). In there the `_totalSupply` parameter is private and works described as in the OpenZeppelin's Fixed Supply' title [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20-supply#fixed-supply). But from what I understand this doesn't stop the contract owner from `mint`ing as many tokens as he/she wants and flooding the market. So,

1. Should I go in and edit the private `_totalSupply` parameter to have a fixed amount of tokens in order to create a more secure token?
2. Am I right? If I apply `1`, would that make it more *secure*?
3. Is there any other way to limit the maximum number of tokens that can exist at any time (in ERC-20 or ERC-1400)?

Answer (score 1):

`_totalSupply` is `internal` (see https://github.com/ConsenSys/UniversalToken/blob/master/contracts/ERC1400.sol#L49), so you can access it in a contract that extends the ERC1400 implementation.

The contract has a method `isIssuable` which return the state of `_isIssuable`. If that is set to `false` (either in a custom constructor or by calling `renounceIssuance`) not more tokens can be created.

What you can do is in the token of your contract that extends ERC1400 you issue the tokens that should available to a wallet that you control and then you disable the possibility to issue more tokens, then your supply is fixed.

Another way is to overwrite the `_issue` function to perform a check before issuing more tokens. E.g that `_totalSupply` is below a specific limit, or that this can only be called at specific time frames.

The general question if you should have a fixed supply or not is very opinion based and depends very heavily on your use case. There are also many "in-between" models: maximum supply (so not fixed, but capped) or fixed inflationary supply (so every x days, y tokens can be minted). So I do not think that there is the general "you should have ... supply".